# Illegal mix of collations for operation 'match'

Tags: mysql

I've got a query like

```
select txt, unix_timestamp(added), uid, id2, id2_type 
  from sitelog 
  where match (id2, uid, txt) against (? in boolean mode)
```

that return this error:

```
Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC), (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC), (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'match'
```

My query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sitelog` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `txt` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id2_type` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `id2` (`id2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

MySQL: 5.5.35+dfsg-0+wheezy1
How does one fix this?

Comment: Why do you want to search in the integer columns uid and id2 with a fulltext search?

Comment: txt is a text field and I'd like to have a single search for these three fields combined.

Comment: that doesn't seem an efficient solution. You've got indexes on both columns and after a `CAST` to INT you should be able to got these few rows with minimal overhead. Using a `UNION` to get your result seems to me straightforward and simple. Sure, you can `CONVERT` or `CAST` your int columns with `USING` the desired collation too. I wouldn't do that in this case.

Comment: Union would only allow me to do OR queries wouldn't it?

Comment: You can do it with OR or otherwise a double UNION. `EXPLAIN` should help to estimate the performance of these queries. Most important is of course the right result. The `CAST` I mentioned will make the use of indexes impossible, said the documentation.